# React: Text editor with styling. (State and UI separated)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I have gone through react components like `<textarea />`, `<ContentEditable />` [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-contenteditable) and many such.

I want to style the text while editing. For example, to color hashtags while typing.

But styling is not possible at all with `<textarea />` or any of them.

For example, The `<ContentEditable />` takes the following props:

```
<ContentEditable
    innerRef={this.contentEditable}
    html={this.state.html} // innerHTML of the editable div
    disabled={false}       // use true to disable editing
    onChange={this.handleChange} // handle innerHTML change
    tagName='article' // Use a custom HTML tag (uses a div by default)
/>
```

Here, The `onChange` event fires when there is a change in whatever passed in `html` prop. Also, `html` doesn't take React components as input.

Theoretically, this is what I want:

The component could be like:

```
<InputComponent 
    onChange={this.changeHandler}
    value={this.state.text}
    displayText={
        <MyReactComponentToStyleTheText>
            {this.state.text}
        </MyReactComponentToStyleTheText>
    }
/>
```

And when the `onChange` fires, it gives us the plain text with the change to work on it.

This may not seem practically possible, but then what does Twitter do to achieve the styling of their hashtags while editing?

Comment: Have you looked at [slate](https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate)? Seems to be a little complex to set up, but it seems to do what you want.

Comment: Nope, Thanks for your suggestion, I'll try it out in some time.